# MySQL: How to count rows (on different conditions) on a filtered data set?

Tags: mysql, group-by, count

With my limited knowledge of MySQL **I cannot find a proper syntax** for what I want to obtain in MySQL (MariaDB 10.0; it is not possible to upgrade it to more recent releases):

1. upload the last 24h of data (in this example: CPU_load; in real
   life it could be a computationally *heavy* filtering and not a simple *last 24h* like in this example);
2. count the values that satisfy different conditions upon the filtered set.

The single query "*how many values are above 95% in the last 24 hours?*" is straightforward:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM (
    SELECT *
    FROM `server-statistics` 
    WHERE `Date_Time` >= DATE_SUB(UTC_TIMESTAMP(), INTERVAL 1 DAY) 
) as H24
WHERE CPU_load > 95
```

For the sake of explanation I left the (here useless) definition of H24.

**Problem**

If I am going to count on multiple conditions (i.e.: *>90% in the last 24h, >95% in the last 24h, >98% in the last 24h, etc.*) with a number of queries like the previous one, the filtered group H24 is recalculated over and over.

This is not a real problem if it is cached among calls, but I would prefer to count the rows on multiple conditions in a single shot.

In pseudo-SQL it should be something like:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) WHERE CPU_load > 90,
       COUNT(*) WHERE CPU_load > 95,
       COUNT(*) WHERE CPU_load > 98
FROM `server-statistics` 
WHERE `Date_Time` >= DATE_SUB(UTC_TIMESTAMP(), INTERVAL 1 DAY)
```

**Is it possible in pure MySQL?**

Comment: should a value counting as above 98% as well be counted as above 95% and above 90% ?

Comment: In real life, yes, but I trying to understand the syntax this is not really important. In the meantime Susang already provided me a working example. Thank you anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `CASE` for the conditional count as below

```
SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN CPU_load BETWEEN 90 AND 94 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS A1,
       SUM(CASE WHEN CPU_load BETWEEN 95 AND 97 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS A2,
       SUM(CASE WHEN CPU_load > 98 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS A3
FROM `server-statistics` 
WHERE `Date_Time` >= DATE_SUB(UTC_TIMESTAMP(), INTERVAL 1 DAY)
```

It seems more meaning to count the data on range but if you still want to stay on your condition then use below instead:

```
SUM(CASE WHEN CPU_load > 90 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS A1
SUM(CASE WHEN CPU_load > 95 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS A2
SUM(CASE WHEN CPU_load > 98 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS A3
```

To address decimal values as 94.5

```
--Adjust the comparison value according to your requirement just provided the example.

SUM(CASE WHEN CPU_load > 90 AND CPU_load <= 95 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS A1
SUM(CASE WHEN CPU_load > 95 AND CPU_load <= 98 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS A2
SUM(CASE WHEN CPU_load > 98 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS A3
```

Comment: if counting on range there could be issues the gaps and decimal scale

Comment: Thank you very much indeed @susang! Just as a minor fix, I had to change your example's labels (1, 2,3) to something valid (A1,A2,A3) because otherwise it would complain about a syntax error.

Comment: @bw_üezi, I upvoted your comment, as I thought you talk about Null values and empty sets. Or is there something else beyond this?

Comment: e.g. value `94.5` is neither `between 90 and 94` not `betwwen 95 and 97`

Comment: Updated to address decimal value as well. You can choose one and adjust comparison value according to your requirement.